# How to add ngx_http_map_module into nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm having problems adding the module [ngx_http_map_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) into my nginx ./conf I tried the `--with-ngx_http_map_module` param but it doesn`t work. I'm kinda new to this so I could be doing something wrong.
After I run that configuration I get this error :

> ./configure: error: invalid option "--with-http_map_module"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading the file [auto/options](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/531e6fbfd6c785a7b42c285c12d3f0721cc989c7/auto/options) gives me the impression that this module is enabled by default.

See the definition [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/531e6fbfd6c785a7b42c285c12d3f0721cc989c7/auto/options#L81):

```
HTTP_MAP=YES
```

and the definition of a `./configure` option [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/531e6fbfd6c785a7b42c285c12d3f0721cc989c7/auto/options#L253):

```
--without-http_map_module
```

Comment: oh dear what a nice link thanks! you are right the module is enabled by default